# Enlazar una publicación a un link para mostrarla en otra página

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Una pregunta... Cómo puedo hacer que el link de una publicación, al darle clic me envíe a otra página y me muestre todo sobre esa publicación?

Estoy usando php y mysqli.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

En el href estoy colocándolo así: "paginadestino.php?id=(<)?php echo '$rows["id_eventos"]'" ?> Pero cuando le doy clic al título de la publicación, me manda a la página destino, en la barra de navegación me muestra el id que le pertenece a la publicación pero se queda cargando y no termina de mostrar la página.

Comment: Puedes poner parte del código donde quieres mostrar la información para poder apoyarte mejor

Comment: En páginadestino.php tengo este código: $id = $_GET['id']; include ("conexion.php"); $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM publi_eventos where id_eventos = '".id."' ";  if(mysqli_num_rows > 0) { while(rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sql) {<?php echo $rows[3]?>  }}

Comment: Hola Crhistian, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, muestranos cua

Comment: te falta un paréntesis en el while, y en `mysqli_fetch_array($sql)` agrega `mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. Si de casualidad lanza un error o un warning hazlo saber.

Comment: Colocándolo así como me indicas funcionaría?

Comment: Intenta, si no funciona, entonces es algo más que hace conflicto, quizás la consulta.

Comment: No me funciona, queda igual cargando la página destino y no muestra nada.

Comment: El código que tengo en la página destino es este:

Comment: <?php 
       $id=$_GET['id'];
       include 'conexion.php';
       error_reporting(0);

       $sqlmostrarev = "SELECT * FROM publi_eventos where id_eventos='".$id."'";
       $resultadoevent = mysqli_query($con, $sqlmostrarev);

       if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlmostrarev) > 0) {

        while($rowss=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlmostrarev)){
      ?>

y luego coloco los echo

Comment: y en la página origen esto: 

<a href="portfolio-details.php?id=<?php echo $rowss['id_eventos']?>" class="btn">Ver Detalles</a>